# Tailwind / React (NextJS) adding custom CSS

Tags: tailwind-css

I have a next.js react application and we're using TailwindCSS which is amazing. But i need to add my own custom css tags and i cant seem to get them to load into the application when compiling.

I have a 'core.css' which is looks like:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
    *:not(i) {
        @apply font-sans;
    }
    p {
        @apply text-base mt-1 mb-1 pt-1 pb-1;
    }
    h1 {
        @apply text-xl;
    }
}

@layer utilities {
    .toggle-checkbox:checked {
        transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        right: 0;
        border-color: #35c759;
    }
    .toggle-checkbox:checked + .toggle-label {
        background-color: #35c759;
        transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
}
```

From what i can gather this should work, but when loading the page i cant find the class definitions when inspecting.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure your core.css is included in your JS file. When you create nextjs app you get the _app.js file by default and you also get global.css file follow that example. So make sure the core.css is included in _app.js file. 

----
The documentation is on tailwindcss documentation is great. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs

Comment: Example video presenting the layer functionality https://youtu.be/pONeWAzDsQg?t=860